# Vbscript to change non admin user IP

Tags: networking, vbscript, passwords, ip, admin

A user once logged in I want to change his IP network to a specific static address. This user should not know the Admin's user password.

So far I have found success with this vbscript

```
'run in elevated mode
If WScript.Arguments.length =0 Then
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  'Pass a bogus argument with leading blank space, say [ uac]
  objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
  WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
Else
  'change IP address
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE") 
strIPAddress = Array("10.5.0.77") 
strSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.0") 
strGateway = Array("10.5.0.1") 
strGatewayMetric = Array(1) 

For Each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters 
    errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(strIPAddress, strSubnetMask) 
    errGateways = objNetAdapter.SetGateways(strGateway, strGatewaymetric) 
Next 
End If
```

The question is how can this script pass the admin password in order for the user not noticing it? (no prompt for admin password)